# How to tightly align columns in react without leaving any spacing

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to create a drop-down of categories in react.

```
function CategoryDropDown() {
  return (
    <>
      {categories.length > 0 &&
        categories.map((category, index) => {
          return (
            <NavDropdown key={index} title={category.name}>
              <Row
                style={{
                  width: "600px",
                  margin: "10px",
                }}
              >
                {category.children?.map((subCategory) => {
                  return (
                    <Col key={index} style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                      <b>{subCategory.name}</b>
                      {subCategory.children?.map((s, index) => {
                        return <div key={index}>{s.name}</div>;
                      })}
                      <hr />
                    </Col>
                  );
                })}
              </Row>
            </NavDropdown>
          );
        })}
    </>
  );
}
```

Category data is going to look like this

```
[
  {
    "name": "abc",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "def",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "xyz",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4mJ8.png

If you see here in the image, second column is having few spaces even though it has fewer items. I want no gaps here and want the row to be started immediately. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Does react support includes of css systems such as Bootstrap?  Because it would be simple to split 2 things since its based on values of 12.  Such as <div class='row'><div class='col-md-6'>(YOUR THING HERE)</div><div class='col-md-6'>THE OTHER SIDE</div></div> and that would do it.  I hate trying to make old <table> systems to work, and just opt for modern tools.

Comment: yes, bootstrap is supported but i did not get the second part of your suggestion. can you show with some sample code if possible ?

Comment: Sure thing, wanted to find out if it would work before I did a type up.  I will make an answer with the info shortly.

Answer (score 1):

If you import the newest Boostrap 5, you can use it to handle the layout with some basic tag use.  What you want is the Grid feature.  If you image the screen from left to right, with 1 being on the left and 12 being on the right, you can break up the screen into segments based of the value of 12.  Being that you want to split the screen with one thing on the left and another on the right, that is simple because half of 12 is 6, so you just need a pair of col-md-6 inside of a row class, as such:

```
<div class='row'>
   <div class='col-md-6'>
      <your left side code here>
   </div>
   <div class='col-md-6'>
        <your right side code here>
    </div>
</div>
```

Citation found here --> https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap5/bootstrap_grid_basic.php

Comment: There is no left part and right part of the code here. As you can see in the code i've pasted, i'm running loops and just want to print data column wise instead of row wise and move towards the right in the same fashion until all data is rendered.

Comment: Well, the left and right can be substituted for 0, and 1 in a loop to go from THIS one to THAT one, and each loop needs the row class, and the end of the loop needs a /div close for that row.  I'm not familiar with react enough to help on this aspect, but i suspect you could do something like what I was saying using this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks this way because you've organized your code as Rows that contain Columns (meaning that each row will have the height of tallest column).  You should instead organize it as Columns that contain Rows, the heights will work themselves out.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but i'm getting like this [link](https://imgur.com/a/tYeAK0f)
If possible, can you please show me the changes by what you meant ?

Comment: Sure give me a moment to edit my answer

Comment: any update on this ?